# Как получить значение переменной, которая лежит вне класса ООП

Tags: php, ооп

Есть переменная, которая содержит массив с настройками. Эти настройки нужны именно в классе.

```
class ClassName{

    private $config = array();

    function __construct($config = array())
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function mymethod()
    {
        return $config["name"];
        // OR
        return $this->config["name"];
    }
}
```

Сейчас приходиться каждый раз при создании объекта, передавать эту переменную и в конструкторе её присваивать и т.д.

Существует ли способ получить её не передавая ничего в конструктор или метод? Так как выходит слишком много кода.

Comment: Настройки статические? Т.е. не меняются, а всегда одни и те же приходят в объект?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan да

Comment: [tsya.ru](http://tsya.ru)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет ничего плохого в указании явной зависимости от конфига в конструкторе.

Можно сделать класс конфига - синглтон.
Потом получайте конфиги через `Config::getInstance()`

*<sub>Минус этого решения(по сравнению с инъекцией зависимости в конструктор) в том, что Singleton - по сути глобальная переменная, вы не сможете подменить его другим классом, например, в тестах. Хотя в данном случае - вы просто подгрузите другие файлы конфигурации.</sub>*

```
class Config implements \ArrayAccess {
  private static $instance;
  private function __construct(){}
  private function __wake(){}
  private function __clone(){}
  public function getInstance(){
    return self::$instance?:self::$instance = new self();
  }
  /*ArrayAccess*/
  public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
    if (is_null($offset)) {
      $this->data[] = $value;
    } else {
      $this->data[$offset] = $value;
    }
  }

  public function offsetExists($offset) {
    return isset($this->data[$offset]);
  }

  public function offsetUnset($offset) {
    unset($this->data[$offset]);
  }

  public function offsetGet($offset) {
    return isset($this->data[$offset]) ? $this->data[$offset] : null;
  }  
  /*Config*/
  private $data = [];
  public function loadJson($filename) {
    $json = file_get_contents($filename);
    $this->load(json_decode($json, true));
  }
  public function load(array $data) {
    $this->data = array_merge($this->data, $data);
  }
}
```

Загружаете конфиг в точке входа:

```
$cfg = Config::getInstance();  
$cfg->loadJson(__DIR__.'/config/general.json'); // общий конфиг, лежит в гит
$cfg->loadJson(__DIR__.'/config/local.json');   // локальный, на каждом сервере свой
$cfg->load(['db' => ['hostname' => '127.0.0.1']]);
```

Используете:

```
class DB {
  public function connect() {
    $cfg = Config::getInstance();
    $host = $cfg['db']['hostname'];
  }
}
```

Comment: То есть создать статический класс в котором будут заданы настройки?

Comment: Лучше не статический, а Singleton.

Comment: @vp_arth а чем Singleton лучше статического класса?

Comment: Тем, что реализация инстанциации объекта проще и очевиднее. Попросту у языка больше средств для работы с инстансами. Принципиальных отличий нет, разумеется. И то, и то - глобальный scope

Answer (score -1):

А из $GLOBALS её взять не? )) Она же всё равно туда попадает и торчит там)))

```
$x_config = array();


class ClassName{

    public function mymethod()
    {
        return $GLOBALS['x_config'];
    }
}
```

или

```
global $x_config;

$x_config = array();


class ClassName{

    public function mymethod()
    {
        global $x_config;

        return $x_config;
    }
}
```